# How to get element to stay on right side of border width 100% width while resizing

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get an image to stay at the right side of the my header element which has a 100% width. The problem is I don't want it to be dragged into other elements in the header when I resize my browser window. I want it to do exactly what the Google.com toolbar does on the result page: how the share button,G+button,etc stay on the right side but when you shrink the browser. they don’t collapse into the search bar and they disappear(that is, the wont remain on the right side) of the element when you shrink it VERY narrow. how is that done??

I know I can change it from percentage to pixels, but I won't be able to be sure if it is on the very right of the browser window on every browser.

sorry if this is really confusing guys, it's kind of a difficult thing for me to articulate,but I will reply to any questions.

an example of the google site is https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=how

Answer (score 1):

## The way Google did it

So, Google is using a relatively new piece of CSS called the flexible box model. With it you can quite easily specify that one of the boxes should size up depending on the window size as such:

```
flex: 1 1 auto;
```

Where it will take up all the additional with in the `display: flex;` parent element. As I don't feel like explaining all about flex in this answer I would advice you to [read this excellent article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes). The disadvantage is that it's not supported in older browsers (specifically IE 9 or 10-). Google is probably serving different CSS files, but I think this adequately already answers the question.

## An alternative way

You could use media queries which change it from `float:right` to a non floated element at the point where the screen width is less than the width of the two elements combined. It's definitely easier to implement and easier to make backwards compatible, but the disadvantage is that the sizes of both elements have to be known.